# Why $f$ is invariant for $G_f$.

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory

Let $F$ a field and $f\in F[X]$ a separable polynomial. Let $K_f$ the splitting field of $f$ and $G_f=Gal(K_f/F)$ its Galois group. We suppose it act transitively on the roots of $f$.$\alpha _1,...,\alpha _n$ the roots of $f$. Then $$f=\prod_{i=1}^n(X-\alpha _i)\in K_f[X].$$
In my solution, it's written that $f$ is invariant by $G_f$ (i.e. $\sigma (f)=f$ for all $\sigma \in G_f$), But to me $$\sigma (f(X))=\sigma \left(\prod_{i=1}^n (X-\alpha_i) \right)=\prod_{i=1}^n(\sigma (X)-\alpha _i)=f(\sigma (X))$$
since $G_f$ act transitively on the roots of $f$. So finally, we don't have $\sigma (f(X))=f(X)$, so what's wrong in my argument ? May be my teacher is wrong and $f$ is not a fix point of $\sigma $, what do you think ?

Comment: What is $\sigma(X)$?

Comment: is ir $X$ ? If yes, why ?@CameronBuie

Comment: I mean, $\sigma (X)=X$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the standard way for the automorphisms $\sigma$ of the field $K_f$ **being extended** to the polynomial ring $K_f[X]$ is precisely by imposing that $\sigma(X)= X$. It is then usually also denoted by $\sigma$. Thus $\sigma(X)= X$ by definition.

Comment: ok great. Thank you for your answer. And not totally understand why. Indeed, let $p(x)=x^2-2$ then $\sigma (p(x))=...=p(\sigma (x))$, and thus if $x$ is a root, $\sigma (x)$ is also a root, but we don't necessarily have $\sigma (x)=x$. Thank you for your explanations, because I don't understand the logical behind the convention $\sigma (x)=x$. @quid

Comment: The issue is what the $x$ signifies. The capital $X$ here denotes "a variable" the little $x$  in your comment an element of some (extension) field. Note that $\sigma$ is an automorphism of $K_f$ but then you apply it to a polynomial over $K_f$. To be able to do this you need to defined it on $X$ in some way. By contrast in the situation of your comment the $\sigma$ is usually an autmorphism of the field of which $x$ is an element. And the $p(x)$ is not a polynomial, but a polynomial exprsion (where already a value is plugged in).

Comment: Well, I used $x$ as $X$. So if you prefer, if $p(X)=X^2-2$, we have that $\sigma (p(X))=...=p(\sigma (X))$. But I don't have any theorem that say that to prolonge $\sigma :F\longrightarrow F$ on $F[X]\longrightarrow F[X]$, we take $\sigma (X)=X$. What would be the justification ? (sorry to insist, but I don't see the logical behind).

Comment: Yes, you have that. But then $X$ is not a root, and the type of arguments you referenced are used in the context I mention. On your question: How else would you prolong $\sigma$ to $F[X]$?  You need to assign some value to $X$, if it were anything but $X$ this ought to be stated somewhere. Usually you should have seen somewhere that every ringhomorphisms of $h:R \to S$ extends to a ringhomormphism of $R[X] $ to $S[X]$ via setting $h(X)= X$ or something like this.